# Does Favored by the Gods work with counterspell rolls?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, sorcerer, counterspelling

I was trying to counterspell *power word kill* and needed the extra rolls. Does Favored by the Gods work with counterspell rolls?

Answer (score 16):

Favored by the Gods states:

> If you fail a **saving throw or miss with an attack roll**, you can roll 2d4 and add it to the total, possibly changing the outcome.

*Counterspell* states

> If it is casting a spell of 4th level or higher, make an **ability check** using your spellcasting ability

Since *Counterspell* requires an ability check, not a saving throw or attack roll, Favored by the Gods cannot be used.

Answer (score 14):

### No

The Favoured By The Gods feature states:

> Starting at 1st level, divine power guards your destiny. If you fail a saving throw or miss with an attack roll, you can roll 2d4 and add it to the total, possibly changing the outcome.

Counterspell says

> If it is Casting a Spell of 4th Level or higher, make an ability check using your Spellcasting Ability.

An ability check is neither an attack roll nor a saving throw, so Favoured By The Gods does not apply.